# Android Google Maps V2 change My Location Icon

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using a custom Icon in my application for the user's current location, and want to keep it this way while upgrading to the new Google Maps library.

With the Google Maps v1 library, i extended MyLocationOverlay and overwritten the drawMyLocation method to draw my custom icon in there.

The GoogleMap enables the current location with the setMyLocationEnabled method, but there's no way to customize it, as far as i know.

Does anybody know how to accomplish this on v2 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so i just figured that if you don't add the title or snippet, the marker will not have effect on a click event, and it acts as an image overlay. Even though it's not perfect, it suits my needs

```
private Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position( latLng)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow)));
```

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 14):

Create a Marker in the map constructor that uses a custom icon.

```
_myLocation = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                      .position(MAP_CENTER)
                      .title("My Location")
                      .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mylocation)));
```

Implement a Location Changed Listener, 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/LocationSource.OnLocationChangedListener

Update the Marker Location when the Provider is called:

```
public void onLocationChanged (Location location)
{
    _myLocation.position(location); //May have to convert from location to LatLng
}
```

Comment: This is the way it was used to be done on the V1 library. In V2, you don't handle the MapView inside an activity. Moreover, there's no Overlay class on V2 to extends from. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/package-summary

Comment: My Bad,  I didn't realize you meant the Google Play version of Maps.  Please see my updated answer above.  This is nice because it is very similar now to how the Google Maps Javascript version behaves.

Comment: @RobertEstivill: AFAIK, this is your only option, at least while sticking with documented/supported behavior.

Comment: The two firsts comments (including this one mine) is obsolete, please remove it.

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely a way to show custom icon on current location.
Checkout [Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker) you will get more idea to customize your icon on map.

Try out the code below :

```
 private static final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.81319, 144.96298);
 private Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(MELBOURNE)
                        .title("Melbourne")
                        .snippet("Population: 4,137,400")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow)));
```

Comment: This can be done, but it's not compatible with the current MyLocation mechanism. In other words, you can use a Marker without all the window information, but you will have to manually implement a LocationListener to move you location drawable around. You can not reuse the built in location capabilities

Comment: This is the only way AFAIK. Please post some code so that i can have idea about your issue. Thank you.